# Get value of the clicked button in code.gs - Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have been trying to follow and implement the answer for same problem but is not working.

I am trying to create a simple approval workflow. I have a form from which I send an email after each response, in this email, I have two buttons to approve or deny the request. I want to recuperate the button value to use it in my code.gs and after the click, i want to show a message to confirm that the answer has been recorded.

**mail.html**
I have this htnl file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">New Request - URL Addition Allow list Fortinet</h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">A new request for allowing a new URL has been submitted:&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">The user {{mail}} has requested the addition of the following URL: <strong>{{url}}</strong></p>


<p style="text-align: center;">
  <button id="Approved"   onclick="buttonClick(this)">Approved</button>
  <button id="Declined"   onclick="buttonClick(this)">Declinedtest</button>
  </p>

<script>
      function buttonClick(button) {
        alert("You clicked "+button.id);
        google.script.run.getButton(button.id);
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs:**

```
function SendMail(e) {
  const res=e.response;
  const respuestas=res.getItemResponses();
  const email=res.getRespondentEmail();
  const mail=respuestas[0].getResponse();
  const url=respuestas[1].getResponse();
  /*Logger.log(mail+url)*/
  const mensaje="The user "+mail+" has requested the addition of the following URL: "+url+"."


  var textoHTML= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("mail2").getContent();
  textoHTML = textoHTML.replace("{{mail}}",mail)
  textoHTML = textoHTML.replace("{{url}}",url)
  GmailApp.sendEmail(mail,"URL Add request",mensaje,{htmlBody:textoHTML})

 function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail2')
}

 function getButton(id) {
  Logger.log("You pressed "+id);
}


}
```

What do I have to recuperate the value of my button? What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?  this is the solution proposed in other's questions but is not working.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify which value you'd like to have and how/where you plan to use it? Is the id from `getButton(id)` being logged? Any exceptions are returned (either in the Execution logs or console)?

Comment: Hi, yes, I want to have the id of the button clicked, which would be "Approved" or "Declined" in each case. No, the id is not been logged. I don't have errors but nothing is being logged. What I want to do with the id is to recuperate this value in my code.gs to be able to assign it to a box in my spreadsheet

Comment: Your `getButton()` is local to `SendMail()` so it is not available from the client.  Move it to global scope.

Comment: I already tried the `getButton()` in global and doesn't work either.

Comment: As spotted by @TheWizEd, both `doGet` and `getButton` are being defined locally to `SendMail`. The `doGet` function must be global in order to serve the HTML. Also make sure to serve the correct HTML file since on the code provided the file veing served is called 'mail2' and the HTML above is mentioned to have the name of 'mail.html'.